# Find Max Value in MySQL Column

Tags: php, mysql

seems like this question has been answered alot, but I can't get it to work!

Have a 'Month' column in DB table, that reaches 313 as max entry.

Am trying to assign this max amount to a PHP value which is working but keeps returning $maxmonth as 99?

Current Coding:

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MAX(Month) AS max from $ulliabforecast");

            {while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() )
            $maxmonth=$row['max'];}
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Perhaps `month` is a `VARCHAR` column?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your `Month` is a `VARCHAR` , you need to do a `CAST` to make it work.

`SELECT MAX(CAST(Month AS SIGNED)) AS max1 from $ulliabforecast`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT `month` FROM $ulliabforecast ORDER BY `month` DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

As your sql query, this should select the largest month column from your database.

Comment: This is pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, but it still returns 99. Don't know why it's not recognizing the max value in the column of 313

Answer (score 0):

You might be using Month column as a `VARCHAR` type, change it to `INT` and your problem will be solved.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You can be using `month` as `VARCHAR`. Please Check.

And if true you can convert it to `UNSIGNED` and then get `Max` out of it

**Please try below `SQL` Statement**

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(`month` AS UNSIGNED)) AS max FROM $ulliabforecast
```

***Note***

As described in [Cast Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast):

> The type for the result can be one of the following values:
>
> - `BINARY[(N)]`
> - `CHAR[(N)]`
> - `DATE`
> - `DATETIME`
> - `DECIMAL[(M[,D])]`
> - `SIGNED [INTEGER]`
> - `TIME`
> - `UNSIGNED [INTEGER]`